# Help pls! Transactionfailed: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted]

Tags: transactions, etherscan

I have a big problem. I made a SLP transaction from the Ronin Bridge (in Axie Infinity) to my Binance wallet and it gave me an error: Warning! Error encountered during contract execution [Reverted].
The SLP has disappeared from Ronin wallet.

The transaction is this: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xb41c3e3ca3cf96712675fadf99b4a260a760be507cc8fbb1a6b744538bfa5481

I have searched a lot and have not found a solution.
Could someone tell me what I can do?

Forgive me if this is not the right forum for this question, but perhaps an expert can help me or give me some advice.

Thank you very much for your attention and excuse my English.

Comment: run `debug.traceTransaction()` as soon as you see it reverted on Etherscan, it will output the field called `returnValue` , use online hex decoder to decode this value, it will show you the text of the revert statement. (Obviously if the contract has the revert string provided at `require()` statement and if the contract was compiled with support for revert strings)

Comment: looks like this contract doesnt have a method called `withdrawERC20For` or does it??